How can I retrieve the address of bitmaps in PROGMEM to show it on OLED display without using a switch..case construct?
I have a rather complex application which controls the number of cups of coffee that are drawn. After different numbers the water tank has to be filled or the coffee grounds has to be discarded.
This application performs well for several years and now I want to add a fan to dry the coffee grounds to prevent mold, which now forms after several days.
The available space in flash is almost eaten up (around 100 bytes left after several loops of optimization).
Randomly bitmaps (smileys) are displayed, the bitmaps are 392 byte in size each, I have 7 of them.
They are stored as follows:
//const unsigned char Sm1Dimension[] PROGMEM = {56, 56};
const unsigned char Smiley1[] PROGMEM = {
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x1f, 0xf8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
    0x03, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x3f, 0xff, 0xff, 0xc0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0x00,
... (cut out several lines of bytes)
    0xfe, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0xf8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x1f, 0xff, 0xc0, 0x00,
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
};
const unsigned char Smiley2[] PROGMEM = {
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x07, 0xff, 0xe0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
    0x3f, 0xff, 0xfc, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xfc, 0x00, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0xe0, 0x00,
... (cut out several lines of bytes)
    0x0f, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x7f, 0xff, 0xfc, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x07, 0xff, 0xe0, 0x00,
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
};
... and so on until 
const unsigned char Smiley7[] PROGMEM = {...};

In the first approach I selected the to be displayed bitmap by means of a switch..case construct which works perfectly. The Adafruit GFX library accepts the pointers and displays the bitmaps as expected.
Below the part of working code:
        switch(cSmileySelect)       // select Smiley
    {
        case 1: 
            pSmileyAdresse = Smiley1;
            break;
        case 2:
            pSmileyAdresse = Smiley2;
            break;
        case 3:
            pSmileyAdresse = Smiley3;
            break;
        case 4:
            pSmileyAdresse = Smiley4;
            break;
        case 5:
            pSmileyAdresse = Smiley5;
            break;
        case 6:
            pSmileyAdresse = Smiley6;
            break;
        case 7:
            pSmileyAdresse = Smiley7;
            break;
        default:    
            pSmileyAdresse = Smiley1;
            break;
    }
// void drawBitmap(int16_t x, int16_t y, uint8_t *bitmap, int16_t width, int16_t height, uint16_t color);
    display.drawBitmap((128 - cSmileyBreite) / 2, 0 + (64 - cSmileyHoehe) / 2, pSmileyAdresse,
            (unsigned int)cSmileyBreite, (unsigned int)cSmileyHoehe, WHITE);

After again experiencing memory shortage when adding the logic to drive a fan, I found, that this switch..case construct uses up plenty of flash.
I tried to replace the switch..case by means of mathematics to derive the pointer to the bitmap in flash, but I get no result.
My test are as so:
pSmileyAdresse = (uint8_t*)(uint16_t)((Smiley7) + (2352 - (((cSmileySelect - 1) % 7) * (sizeof(Smiley7))  )));

The magic number 2352 is the size of the complete array of 7 smileys, the bitmaps are stored in descending order (smiley7 at the lowest address).
My expectation was, adding the size of each Smiley bitmap should derive the address of the next smiley, but to no avail.
Next approach was, to build up an array of pointers to the smileys...
const unsigned char*  Smileys[] = {
&Smiley1[0], &Smiley2[0], &Smiley3[0], &Smiley4[0], &Smiley5[0], &Smiley6[0], &Smiley7[0], &Smiley13_bw[0]
};

...and get the address of the selected smiley by this:
pSmileyAdresse = (const uint8_t*)(Smileys[cSmileySelect - 1][0]);

This might have worked, but this small addition to my code swells the code in flash by 3166 byte, busting the maximum by ~2000 byte.
Why this?
And lastly:
Is there a way of deriving the PROGMEM addresses of the smileys by simple mathematics, not busting the flash limit?
Thanks!

the bitmaps are 392 byte in size each, I have 7 of them. Is that always the case? Then have one big array of size 392 * 7 bytes and index them with const byte* &bigArray[smileyId * 392];, with smileyId being from 0 to 6 inclusive.

This works in principle, but the resulting code size of 31236 again busts the available 30720 byte of the arduino.

.. this is the most compact way to store the data. One contiguous array. Zero overhead. If that sketch as a whole overflows Flash, you might need to look into different / slimmer display libraries like u8g2. Hard to say where the other memory usage lies without seeing the full sketch. The image data should only take up 2744 bytes.

I fear, I initially was mislead into thinking, discarding the switch..case construct frees up plenty of codespace.
Most likely, by discarding the switch..case the optimizing linker throws away the complete array of bitmaps, since they are never used again without the switch..case.
Is that conceivable?
This would explain to me, that with all possible methods to access the bitmaps, I every time fell into flash space distress in roughly the size of the sum of the bitmaps sizes.

Do you have a minimal, reproducable example for this?

I can derive it from the original code. What should it contain? Only the bitmaps part and the routine to display them? You don't need to change the bitmaps, do you?

I have the minimal version on hand, alas 685 lines of code, still. Where should I place it? (Comments are too short)

The initial question arose when I was on search for code optimization to free flash memory for further enhancing the program by additional functions. I back then found, that commenting out the switch...case construct, I used to get the adress of the to be displayed bitmap, frees a considerable amount of flash space.
But I missed the fact, that the now no longer referenced bitmaps are optimized away by the linker.
So I was mislead into thinking, the switch...case construct uses up so much space and has to be replaced by something more efficient.
In the end, supported by @Maximilian and @hcheung, I found, that every approach leads to the same memory shortage as the initial switch...case construct.
Finally: No solution but gain in knowledge :)


void drawBitmap(int16_t x, int16_t y, uint8_t *bitmap, int16_t width, int16_t height, uint16_t color);

AdafruitGFX offers two overloaded methods for drawBitmap(). This particular method allows you to pass in a pointer to a bitmap that is located in the RAM, as you can see from the source code, it doesn't read the data from the PROGMEM, but simply get a byte with b = bitmap[j * byteWidth + i / 8];. So if you are calling the method with the function signature, data need to be first copy into a ram buffer and calling the function with the pointer to ram buffer, obviously that would take up to the RAM memory of the size of Smileyx.
The correct API to call is the second overloaded method:
void Adafruit_GFX::drawBitmap(int16_t x, int16_t y, const uint8_t bitmap[], int16_t w, int16_t h, uint16_t color)

Noticed that the subtle difference is the const uint8_t bitmap[] and the source code indicated that it read a byte directly from the PROGMEM with:
b = pgm_read_byte(&bitmap[j * byteWidth + i / 8]);

This would take only 1 byte of RAM to store the b instead of the size of Smiley1. To use this method, all it needs is to directly pass in the Smiley1 as:
display.drawBitmap(x, y, Smiley1, w, h, color);


This works perfect with just one bitmap to display. But I have to iterate through the array of bitmaps to show each time a different one.
I'm unable to find the solution for this approach. I tried all kinds of casting to get a variable pointer into the array of bitmaps.
As you already stated, the given function requires a "const uint8_t" as parameter for the bitmap.
If I try to assign this parameter a variation (to select one of 7 available), the compiler complains with "the expression has to be an alterable lvalue". I assume this is deterred by "const".

You could have a two dimensional array const unit8_t smileys[][7] = { {...}, {...}, ... {...}}; to combined all the array into one, and access it with display.drawBitmap(x, y, smileys[smileySelect], w, h, color);.

Minor corrections needed
const uint8_t smileys[7][392] PROGMEM = { {...}, {...}, ... {...}};
but then it works.
As with all other approaches, this in the end busts the flash size.
I think, I have to reduce the number of smileys to get the expanded code to fit into the Arduino flash. Thanks anyway!
